# Office Addin - reading web.config appsettings for debug and release

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am developing an Office Addin for excel using Visual Studio 2019. I have different settings like API urls, default user etc for debug and release. I want to save these settings in web.debug.config and web.release.config and let visual studio pick settings from the relevant file based on whether I am running project in debug or release mode.
Or if it is not possible to do read web.config file in JS, then is there a way to know if application is running in debug or release mode, so that I set these values accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a standard [web.config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-5.0). This is a standard file for configuring a web application (which is actually what an Office add-in is) that is hosted on the IIS/ASP stack.

In the pre-build or post-build actions you may copy an appropriate content/file to the output folder and use different content or configuration that way.